# FIFA 13 cross-platform, any differences?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, fifa-13

My friend bought Fifa 13 on Xbox and everybody's getting excited for tournaments etc. I only have a PC however, so I'm wondering, if I get Fifa 13 on PC, will I be able to accurately practice and learn the game and then transfer that knowledge? Or is there possibly some weird difference to cater for the PC audience, or perhaps some bad porting issues?

I'm certainly expecting this to be a no, but I just can't find any info on it.

For bonus points, would anybody recommend getting FIFA 12 PC for learning FIFA 13 Xbox? I'm not expecting to be a masterclass, my main goal is to learn the control schemes, but obviously the closest it can be to the Fifa 13 Xbox the better.

THanks!

Comment: On your subquestion... Fifa 13 has some major changes to the gameplay. Practising on Fifa 12 will certainly help you in some ways, but you will likely find it very difficult to defend well when you first start playing 13.

Comment: Yeah I have found the defending to be quite difficult anyway, having previously played FIFA from 01/02 :). Never have been much of a defender, but in 13 I'm feeling pretty useless so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I went ahead and bought it, and I must say that from a gameplay point of view I'm not able to identify any differences between FIFA 13 Xbox vs PC. The control schemes map exactly as far as I can tell.

Comment: Usually for the FIFA franchise in the last few years, the PC/Mac/x360/PS3 version are identical (Save for console specific features like Kinect support), and there are different version for the Wii, PS2, PSP, Vita, DS and 3DS.

Comment: Yeah one of my reasons for asking was all the complaints about the Wii version. Couldn't help myself though, and now my hands hurt from excessive playing. Go Barnet!